How to structure prompt response to be comma and space delimited?
I have found many questions pertaining to my question but none with the specific situation I find myself in. I have a script that is asking for a user response in order to put into a function. It is provided below.
askforQC_type <- \(qctype){
  qctype <- readline("What QC types would you like to run?") 
  qualitycontroltypes <- c('BLK', 'DDL', 'DUP', 'FBLK', 'LCS', 'LCSD', 'LDUP', 'LMB', 'MS', 'MSD', 'NO3', 'RNS', 'SO4', 'SPI', 'SPL', 'TBLK')
  if(qctype %in% qualitycontroltypes) {
    writeLines(paste("QC types chosen:", qctype))
  } else {
      writeLines(paste("Sorry,", qctype, "contains a QC type that is not applicable"))
    }
}

When running askforQC_type() it will accept an answer such as DUP, but will not accept the answer is if run it like DUP, RNS, SPL. Here are some examples below:
#success
 askforQC_type()
What QC types would you like to run? DUP
QC types chosen: DUP

#fail
askforQC_type()
What QC types would you like to run? DUP, RNS, SPL
Sorry, DUP, RNS, SPL contains a QC type that is not applicable

I am wondering how to provide the prompt with an answer such as the one provided in the failed one and interpret it correctly. Additionally, how would I go about adding an ALL response in order to be able to run the function using all values in the qualitycontroltypes vector? Thanks and let me know if any further information is needed.

You are passing in the string "DUP, RNS, SPL" not the vector "DUP", "RNS", "SPL". Here is one potential fix:
askforQC_type <- \(qctype){
  qctype <- readline("What QC types would you like to run?") 
  response <- trimws(strsplit("DUP, RNS, SPL", ",")[[1]], "both") # <- added
  qualitycontroltypes <- c('BLK', 'DDL', 'DUP', 'FBLK', 'LCS', 'LCSD', 'LDUP', 'LMB', 'MS', 'MSD', 'NO3', 'RNS', 'SO4', 'SPI', 'SPL', 'TBLK')
  if(all(response %in% qualitycontroltypes)) { # <- modified
    writeLines(paste("QC types chosen:", qctype))
  } else {
    writeLines(paste("Sorry,", qctype, "contains a QC type that is not applicable"))
  }
}

Explanation
To help you see I added a print statement to your function:
askforQC_type <- \(qctype){
  qctype <- readline("What QC types would you like to run?") 
  print(qctype)
  qualitycontroltypes <- c('BLK', 'DDL', 'DUP', 'FBLK', 'LCS', 'LCSD', 'LDUP', 'LMB', 'MS', 'MSD', 'NO3', 'RNS', 'SO4', 'SPI', 'SPL', 'TBLK')
  if(qctype %in% qualitycontroltypes) {
    writeLines(paste("QC types chosen:", qctype))
  } else {
    writeLines(paste("Sorry,", qctype, "contains a QC type that is not applicable"))
  }
}

askforQC_type()
What QC types would you like to run? DUP, RNS, SPL
[1] "DUP, RNS, SPL"
Sorry, DUP, RNS, SPL contains a QC type that is not applicable

As you can see it is returning a character vector with one element: [1] "DUP, RNS, SPL". So your conditional statement returns FALSE:
"DUP, RNS, SPL" %in% c('BLK', 'DDL', 'DUP', 'FBLK', 'LCS', 'LCSD', 'LDUP', 'LMB', 'MS', 'MSD', 'NO3', 'RNS', 'SO4', 'SPI', 'SPL', 'TBLK')
# [1] FALSE


Ok, I see the problem now. How would I go about fixing it?

Split the response into a vector and compare it to qualitycontroltypes. You will likely want to test if all() are in your vector. See edits.
